# Moviepy: add audio to a video

Tags: python-3.x, audio, video, moviepy

I am trying to run the following code:

```
from moviepy.editor import *
videoclip = VideoFileClip("filename.mp4")
audioclip = AudioFileClip("audioname.mp3")

new_audioclip = CompositeAudioClip([videoclip.audio, audioclip])
videoclip.audio = new_audioclip
videoclip.write_videofile("new_filename.mp4")
```

but when I run it I got the following error:

*
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:/Users/arthu/PycharmProjects/Comprei da China/video.py", line 5, in 
    new_audioclip = CompositeAudioClip([videoclip.audio, audioclip])   File "C:\Users\arthu\PycharmProjects\Comprei da China\venv\lib\site-packages\moviepy\audio\AudioClip.py", line 285, in
**init**
    ends = [c.end for c in self.clips]   File "C:\Users\arthu\PycharmProjects\Comprei da China\venv\lib\site-packages\moviepy\audio\AudioClip.py", line 285, in 
    ends = [c.end for c in self.clips] AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'end'
*

Does anybody know how can I solve that?

Answer (score 24):

Pass only one parameter in CompositeAudioClip  the built in class AudioClip.py has one parameter

```
from moviepy.editor import *
videoclip = VideoFileClip("filename.mp4")
audioclip = AudioFileClip("audioname.mp3")

new_audioclip = CompositeAudioClip([audioclip])
videoclip.audio = new_audioclip
videoclip.write_videofile("new_filename.mp4")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is trickier than it should be:

1. You must monkey-patch your moviepy `ffmpeg_writer.py` to remove the `-an` flag ([See this related SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72374460/3853537)). The code should be:

```py
        # order is important
        cmd = [
            get_setting("FFMPEG_BINARY"),
            '-y',
            '-loglevel', 'error' if logfile == sp.PIPE else 'info',
            '-f', 'rawvideo',
            '-vcodec', 'rawvideo',
            '-s', '%dx%d' % (size[0], size[1]),
            '-pix_fmt', 'rgba' if withmask else 'rgb24',
            '-r', '%.02f' % fps,
            # '-an',
            '-i',
            '-'
        ]
```

2. Don't use the `audio='your_audio_file.mp3'` in `.write_video(audio='your_audio_file.mp3', audio_codec='aac')`. Because moviepy will copy the codec regardless of your `audio_codec='aac'`

```py
        if audiofile is not None:
            cmd.extend([
                '-i', audiofile,
                '-acodec', 'copy'
            ])
```