# Adding music to `VideoClip` doesn't work - moviepy

Tags: python, audio, video, moviepy, background-music

I am concatenating 1 `ImageClip` with 2 `VideoClip`s and my goal is to add the music to the concatenated video, but the music might be different length as the video, so I use `subclip` to cut the music, and add a little fade out at end. But, my problem is... that no audio is written to the video... I tried using VLC player, adding codecs... But nothing worked.

My current code is:

```
from moviepy.editor import *

for_delivery = concatenate([ImageClip('img.jpg').set_duration(3), VideoFileClip('a.mp4'), VideoFileClip('b.mp4')], method='chain')
music_file = AudioFileClip('coolmusic.mp3')
for_delivery = for_delivery.set_audio(music_file.subclip(0, for_delivery.duration).audio_fadeout(2))
for_delivery.write_videofile(target_path, fps=clip.fps, bitrate='%dK' % (bitrate), threads=50, preset='superfast', verbose=False, logger=None, write_logfile=True)
```

For some reason, no audio is written to the video. The video is concatenated as desired, but the video is outputted without any sound.

The logfile output is:

```
ffmpeg version 4.3.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 10.2.1 (GCC) 20200726
  configuration: --disable-static --enable-shared --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libdav1d --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libsrt --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libgsm --enable-librav1e --disable-w32threads --enable-libmfx --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt --enable-amf
  libavutil      56. 51.100 / 56. 51.100
  libavcodec     58. 91.100 / 58. 91.100
  libavformat    58. 45.100 / 58. 45.100
  libavdevice    58. 10.100 / 58. 10.100
  libavfilter     7. 85.100 /  7. 85.100
  libswscale      5.  7.100 /  5.  7.100
  libswresample   3.  7.100 /  3.  7.100
  libpostproc    55.  7.100 / 55.  7.100
Input #0, rawvideo, from 'pipe:':
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1491499 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (RGB[24] / 0x18424752), rgb24, 1920x1080, 1491499 kb/s, 29.97 tbr, 29.97 tbn, 29.97 tbc
Input #1, mp3, from 'demo-testTEMP_MPY_wvf_snd.mp3':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.45.100
  Duration: 00:01:06.04, start: 0.025057, bitrate: 128 kb/s
    Stream #1:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.91
Please use -b:a or -b:v, -b is ambiguous
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (rawvideo (native) -> h264 (libx264))
[libx264 @ 000001f00526ec00] Application has requested 50 threads. Using a thread count greater than 16 is not recommended.
[libx264 @ 000001f00526ec00] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2 AVX512
[libx264 @ 000001f00526ec00] profile High, level 4.0, 4:2:0, 8-bit
[libx264 @ 000001f00526ec00] 264 - core 161 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2020 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=1 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x3 me=dia subme=1 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=0 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=0 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=0 threads=50 lookahead_threads=8 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=1 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc=abr mbtree=0 bitrate=7833 ratetol=1.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 pb_ratio=1.30 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'demo-test.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.45.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080, q=-1--1, 7833 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 11988 tbn, 29.97 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.91.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/7833000 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: N/A
[rawvideo @ 000001f005266340] Thread message queue blocking; consider raising the thread_queue_size option (current value: 8)
frame=   40 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   0x    
frame=   82 fps= 81 q=15.0 size=    1024kB time=00:00:00.73 bitrate=11426.8kbits/s speed=0.724x    
frame=  120 fps= 79 q=13.0 size=    2048kB time=00:00:02.00 bitrate=8380.1kbits/s speed=1.31x    
frame=  124 fps= 61 q=12.0 size=    2048kB time=00:00:02.13 bitrate=7856.3kbits/s speed=1.05x    
frame=  128 fps= 50 q=11.0 size=    2048kB time=00:00:02.26 bitrate=7394.2kbits/s speed=0.89x    
frame=  131 fps= 43 q=15.0 size=    2048kB time=00:00:02.36 bitrate=7081.8kbits/s speed=0.777x    
frame=  134 fps= 38 q=16.0 size=    2048kB time=00:00:02.46 bitrate=6794.7kbits/s speed=0.695x    
frame=  137 fps= 34 q=16.0 size=    2048kB time=00:00:02.56 bitrate=6530.0kbits/s speed=0.633x    
frame=  141 fps= 31 q=18.0 size=    2048kB time=00:00:02.70 bitrate=6207.5kbits/s speed=0.591x    
frame=  144 fps= 28 q=20.0 size=    2048kB time=00:00:02.80 bitrate=5985.8kbits/s speed=0.551x    
frame=  147 fps= 26 q=19.0 size=    2048kB time=00:00:02.90 bitrate=5779.4kbits/s speed=0.519x    
frame=  150 fps= 25 q=18.0 size=    2048kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate=5586.8kbits/s speed=0.492x    
frame=  159 fps= 24 q=15.0 size=    2048kB time=00:00:03.30 bitrate=5078.9kbits/s speed=0.499x    
frame=  168 fps= 24 q=15.0 size=    2048kB time=00:00:03.60 bitrate=4655.7kbits/s speed=0.505x    
frame=  177 fps= 23 q=15.0 size=    2048kB time=00:00:03.90 bitrate=4297.6kbits/s speed=0.511x    
frame=  185 fps= 23 q=15.0 size=    3072kB time=00:00:04.17 bitrate=6033.7kbits/s speed=0.512x    
frame=  195 fps= 23 q=19.0 size=    5120kB time=00:00:04.50 bitrate=9311.3kbits/s speed=0.521x    
frame=  204 fps= 22 q=26.0 size=    6656kB time=00:00:04.80 bitrate=11348.1kbits/s speed=0.525x    
frame=  213 fps= 22 q=26.0 size=    8448kB time=00:00:05.10 bitrate=13556.1kbits/s speed=0.528x    
frame=  222 fps= 22 q=27.0 size=   10496kB time=00:00:05.40 bitrate=15906.7kbits/s speed=0.531x    
frame=  231 fps= 22 q=28.0 size=   12288kB time=00:00:05.70 bitrate=17642.4kbits/s speed=0.534x    
frame=  240 fps= 21 q=28.0 size=   13312kB time=00:00:06.00 bitrate=18157.0kbits/s speed=0.536x    
frame=  249 fps= 21 q=30.0 size=   14336kB time=00:00:06.30 bitrate=18622.5kbits/s speed=0.539x    
frame=  257 fps= 21 q=31.0 size=   14592kB time=00:00:06.57 bitrate=18185.3kbits/s speed=0.539x    
frame=  266 fps= 21 q=31.0 size=   15104kB time=00:00:06.87 bitrate=18001.0kbits/s speed=0.54x    
frame=  275 fps= 21 q=32.0 size=   15616kB time=00:00:07.17 bitrate=17832.2kbits/s speed=0.542x    
frame=  284 fps= 21 q=35.0 size=   16128kB time=00:00:07.47 bitrate=17676.9kbits/s speed=0.544x    
frame=  293 fps= 21 q=33.0 size=   16640kB time=00:00:07.77 bitrate=17533.6kbits/s speed=0.546x    
frame=  301 fps= 20 q=33.0 size=   16896kB time=00:00:08.04 bitrate=17212.4kbits/s speed=0.545x    
frame=  310 fps= 20 q=33.0 size=   17152kB time=00:00:08.34 bitrate=16844.1kbits/s speed=0.546x    
frame=  319 fps= 20 q=33.0 size=   17408kB time=00:00:08.64 bitrate=16501.5kbits/s speed=0.548x    
frame=  328 fps= 20 q=33.0 size=   17664kB time=00:00:08.94 bitrate=16181.8kbits/s speed=0.548x    
frame=  336 fps= 20 q=33.0 size=   17920kB time=00:00:09.20 bitrate=15940.5kbits/s speed=0.548x    
frame=  345 fps= 20 q=35.0 size=   17920kB time=00:00:09.50 bitrate=15437.2kbits/s speed=0.549x    
frame=  353 fps= 20 q=30.0 size=   18176kB time=00:00:09.77 bitrate=15230.2kbits/s speed=0.548x    
frame=  362 fps= 20 q=26.0 size=   18432kB time=00:00:10.07 bitrate=14984.4kbits/s speed=0.549x    
frame=  372 fps= 20 q=24.0 size=   18688kB time=00:00:10.41 bitrate=14705.6kbits/s speed=0.552x    
frame=  382 fps= 20 q=24.0 size=   18688kB time=00:00:10.74 bitrate=14248.9kbits/s speed=0.555x    
frame=  391 fps= 20 q=32.0 size=   18944kB time=00:00:11.04 bitrate=14051.4kbits/s speed=0.556x    
frame=  400 fps= 20 q=30.0 size=   18944kB time=00:00:11.34 bitrate=13679.4kbits/s speed=0.557x    
frame=  409 fps= 20 q=23.0 size=   19200kB time=00:00:11.64 bitrate=13506.7kbits/s speed=0.557x    
frame=  418 fps= 20 q=24.0 size=   19200kB time=00:00:11.94 bitrate=13167.2kbits/s speed=0.558x    
frame=  427 fps= 19 q=24.0 size=   19200kB time=00:00:12.24 bitrate=12844.3kbits/s speed=0.559x    
frame=  436 fps= 19 q=31.0 size=   19200kB time=00:00:12.54 bitrate=12536.8kbits/s speed=0.56x    
frame=  445 fps= 19 q=31.0 size=   19456kB time=00:00:12.84 bitrate=12407.0kbits/s speed=0.56x    
frame=  454 fps= 19 q=30.0 size=   19456kB time=00:00:13.14 bitrate=12123.6kbits/s speed=0.561x    
frame=  463 fps= 19 q=29.0 size=   19456kB time=00:00:13.44 bitrate=11852.9kbits/s speed=0.561x    
frame=  472 fps= 19 q=29.0 size=   19456kB time=00:00:13.74 bitrate=11594.0kbits/s speed=0.562x    
frame=  480 fps= 19 q=28.0 size=   19456kB time=00:00:14.01 bitrate=11373.1kbits/s speed=0.561x    
frame=  489 fps= 19 q=29.0 size=   19712kB time=00:00:14.31 bitrate=11281.0kbits/s speed=0.561x    
frame=  498 fps= 19 q=30.0 size=   19968kB time=00:00:14.61 bitrate=11192.7kbits/s speed=0.562x    
frame=  507 fps= 19 q=29.0 size=   19968kB time=00:00:14.91 bitrate=10967.4kbits/s speed=0.563x    
frame=  516 fps= 19 q=29.0 size=   20224kB time=00:00:15.21 bitrate=10888.7kbits/s speed=0.563x    
frame=  524 fps= 19 q=29.0 size=   20480kB time=00:00:15.48 bitrate=10836.5kbits/s speed=0.562x    
frame=  533 fps= 19 q=31.0 size=   20736kB time=00:00:15.78 bitrate=10763.1kbits/s speed=0.563x    
frame=  542 fps= 19 q=31.0 size=   20736kB time=00:00:16.08 bitrate=10562.2kbits/s speed=0.563x    
frame=  551 fps= 19 q=31.0 size=   20992kB time=00:00:16.38 bitrate=10496.6kbits/s speed=0.564x    
frame=  560 fps= 19 q=29.0 size=   20992kB time=00:00:16.68 bitrate=10307.6kbits/s speed=0.564x    
frame=  569 fps= 19 q=30.0 size=   20992kB time=00:00:16.98 bitrate=10125.4kbits/s speed=0.565x    
frame=  578 fps= 19 q=30.0 size=   21248kB time=00:00:17.28 bitrate=10070.8kbits/s speed=0.565x    
frame=  587 fps= 19 q=30.0 size=   21248kB time=00:00:17.58 bitrate=9898.8kbits/s speed=0.565x    
frame=  596 fps= 19 q=27.0 size=   21248kB time=00:00:17.88 bitrate=9732.6kbits/s speed=0.566x    
frame=  605 fps= 19 q=29.0 size=   21504kB time=00:00:18.18 bitrate=9687.2kbits/s speed=0.566x    
frame=  614 fps= 19 q=29.0 size=   21504kB time=00:00:18.48 bitrate=9529.8kbits/s speed=0.566x    
frame=  622 fps= 19 q=30.0 size=   21760kB time=00:00:18.75 bitrate=9506.0kbits/s speed=0.566x    
frame=  631 fps= 19 q=27.0 size=   21760kB time=00:00:19.05 bitrate=9356.2kbits/s speed=0.566x    
frame=  640 fps= 19 q=29.0 size=   21760kB time=00:00:19.35 bitrate=9211.0kbits/s speed=0.567x    
frame=  649 fps= 19 q=29.0 size=   22016kB time=00:00:19.65 bitrate=9177.0kbits/s speed=0.567x    
frame=  658 fps= 19 q=26.0 size=   22016kB time=00:00:19.95 bitrate=9038.8kbits/s speed=0.567x    
frame=  660 fps= 18 q=28.0 size=   22016kB time=00:00:20.02 bitrate=9008.7kbits/s speed=0.561x    
frame=  664 fps= 18 q=25.0 size=   22272kB time=00:00:20.15 bitrate=9053.1kbits/s speed=0.557x    
frame=  667 fps= 18 q=27.0 size=   22272kB time=00:00:20.25 bitrate=9008.4kbits/s speed=0.552x    
frame=  670 fps= 18 q=24.0 size=   22272kB time=00:00:20.35 bitrate=8964.1kbits/s speed=0.547x    
frame=  673 fps= 18 q=27.0 size=   22272kB time=00:00:20.45 bitrate=8920.2kbits/s speed=0.542x    
frame=  677 fps= 18 q=27.0 size=   22272kB time=00:00:20.58 bitrate=8862.4kbits/s speed=0.538x    
frame=  680 fps= 18 q=27.0 size=   22272kB time=00:00:20.68 bitrate=8819.5kbits/s speed=0.534x    
frame=  683 fps= 17 q=26.0 size=   22272kB time=00:00:20.78 bitrate=8777.0kbits/s speed=0.53x    
frame=  686 fps= 17 q=28.0 size=   22528kB time=00:00:20.88 bitrate=8835.4kbits/s speed=0.525x    
frame=  689 fps= 17 q=26.0 size=   22528kB time=00:00:20.98 bitrate=8793.2kbits/s speed=0.521x    
frame=  699 fps= 17 q=27.0 size=   22784kB time=00:00:21.32 bitrate=8754.0kbits/s speed=0.523x    
frame=  707 fps= 17 q=25.0 size=   22784kB time=00:00:21.58 bitrate=8645.7kbits/s speed=0.523x    
frame=  716 fps= 17 q=26.0 size=   22784kB time=00:00:21.88 bitrate=8527.1kbits/s speed=0.524x    
frame=  725 fps= 17 q=27.0 size=   23040kB time=00:00:22.18 bitrate=8506.2kbits/s speed=0.524x    
frame=  734 fps= 17 q=26.0 size=   23296kB time=00:00:22.48 bitrate=8485.9kbits/s speed=0.525x    
frame=  743 fps= 17 q=24.0 size=   23296kB time=00:00:22.78 bitrate=8374.1kbits/s speed=0.526x    
frame=  752 fps= 17 q=26.0 size=   23552kB time=00:00:23.08 bitrate=8356.0kbits/s speed=0.526x    
frame=  761 fps= 17 q=23.0 size=   23808kB time=00:00:23.39 bitrate=8338.4kbits/s speed=0.527x    
frame=  769 fps= 17 q=25.0 size=   23808kB time=00:00:23.65 bitrate=8244.3kbits/s speed=0.527x    
frame=  778 fps= 17 q=23.0 size=   23808kB time=00:00:23.95 bitrate=8140.9kbits/s speed=0.528x    
frame=  787 fps= 17 q=25.0 size=   24064kB time=00:00:24.25 bitrate=8126.6kbits/s speed=0.528x    
frame=  796 fps= 17 q=25.0 size=   24320kB time=00:00:24.55 bitrate=8112.6kbits/s speed=0.529x    
frame=  805 fps= 17 q=23.0 size=   24320kB time=00:00:24.85 bitrate=8014.6kbits/s speed=0.53x    
frame=  813 fps= 17 q=25.0 size=   24576kB time=00:00:25.12 bitrate=8012.9kbits/s speed=0.53x    
frame=  820 fps= 17 q=25.0 size=   24832kB time=00:00:25.35 bitrate=8021.8kbits/s speed=0.529x    
frame=  828 fps= 17 q=22.0 size=   24832kB time=00:00:25.62 bitrate=7938.3kbits/s speed=0.529x    
frame=  835 fps= 17 q=17.0 size=   25088kB time=00:00:25.85 bitrate=7947.7kbits/s speed=0.528x    
frame=  846 fps= 17 q=14.0 size=   25344kB time=00:00:26.22 bitrate=7916.4kbits/s speed=0.53x    
frame=  861 fps= 17 q=16.0 size=   25856kB time=00:00:26.72 bitrate=7925.1kbits/s speed=0.535x    
frame=  875 fps= 17 q=14.0 size=   26112kB time=00:00:27.19 bitrate=7866.1kbits/s speed=0.539x    
frame=  889 fps= 17 q=15.0 size=   26112kB time=00:00:27.66 bitrate=7733.2kbits/s speed=0.542x    
frame=  903 fps= 18 q=14.0 size=   26368kB time=00:00:28.12 bitrate=7679.4kbits/s speed=0.546x    
frame=  917 fps= 18 q=23.0 size=   26368kB time=00:00:28.59 bitrate=7553.9kbits/s speed=0.55x    
frame=  930 fps= 18 q=23.0 size=   26368kB time=00:00:29.02 bitrate=7441.0kbits/s speed=0.553x    
frame=  946 fps= 18 q=22.0 size=   26368kB time=00:00:29.56 bitrate=7306.7kbits/s speed=0.557x    
frame=  961 fps= 18 q=20.0 size=   26624kB time=00:00:30.06 bitrate=7254.8kbits/s speed=0.561x    
frame=  975 fps= 18 q=22.0 size=   27392kB time=00:00:30.53 bitrate=7349.9kbits/s speed=0.565x    
frame=  990 fps= 18 q=22.0 size=   27904kB time=00:00:31.03 bitrate=7366.5kbits/s speed=0.569x    
frame= 1006 fps= 18 q=22.0 size=   28672kB time=00:00:31.56 bitrate=7441.2kbits/s speed=0.573x    
frame= 1021 fps= 18 q=22.0 size=   29184kB time=00:00:32.06 bitrate=7455.9kbits/s speed=0.577x    
frame= 1036 fps= 18 q=21.0 size=   29952kB time=00:00:32.56 bitrate=7534.5kbits/s speed=0.581x    
frame= 1052 fps= 19 q=24.0 size=   30464kB time=00:00:33.09 bitrate=7539.7kbits/s speed=0.585x    
frame= 1069 fps= 19 q=24.0 size=   31232kB time=00:00:33.66 bitrate=7599.5kbits/s speed=0.59x    
frame= 1085 fps= 19 q=23.0 size=   31744kB time=00:00:34.20 bitrate=7603.5kbits/s speed=0.594x    
frame= 1102 fps= 19 q=24.0 size=   32512kB time=00:00:34.76 bitrate=7660.4kbits/s speed=0.598x    
frame= 1117 fps= 19 q=23.0 size=   33024kB time=00:00:35.26 bitrate=7670.6kbits/s speed=0.602x    
frame= 1133 fps= 19 q=22.0 size=   33536kB time=00:00:35.80 bitrate=7673.4kbits/s speed=0.605x    
frame= 1148 fps= 19 q=23.0 size=   33792kB time=00:00:36.30 bitrate=7625.4kbits/s speed=0.609x    
frame= 1163 fps= 19 q=22.0 size=   34304kB time=00:00:36.80 bitrate=7635.6kbits/s speed=0.612x    
frame= 1179 fps= 19 q=22.0 size=   34816kB time=00:00:37.33 bitrate=7638.8kbits/s speed=0.615x    
frame= 1195 fps= 20 q=23.0 size=   35584kB time=00:00:37.87 bitrate=7697.2kbits/s speed=0.619x    
frame= 1210 fps= 20 q=25.0 size=   36096kB time=00:00:38.37 bitrate=7706.2kbits/s speed=0.622x    
frame= 1226 fps= 20 q=25.0 size=   36864kB time=00:00:38.90 bitrate=7762.1kbits/s speed=0.626x    
frame= 1243 fps= 20 q=23.0 size=   37376kB time=00:00:39.47 bitrate=7756.8kbits/s speed=0.63x    
frame= 1258 fps= 20 q=26.0 size=   38144kB time=00:00:39.97 bitrate=7817.1kbits/s speed=0.632x    
frame= 1274 fps= 20 q=26.0 size=   38912kB time=00:00:40.50 bitrate=7869.4kbits/s speed=0.636x    
frame= 1289 fps= 20 q=26.0 size=   39424kB time=00:00:41.00 bitrate=7875.6kbits/s speed=0.638x    
frame= 1304 fps= 20 q=26.0 size=   40192kB time=00:00:41.50 bitrate=7932.2kbits/s speed=0.641x    
frame= 1320 fps= 20 q=22.0 size=   40704kB time=00:00:42.04 bitrate=7931.3kbits/s speed=0.644x    
frame= 1336 fps= 20 q=23.0 size=   41472kB time=00:00:42.57 bitrate=7979.6kbits/s speed=0.647x    
frame= 1351 fps= 20 q=22.0 size=   41984kB time=00:00:43.07 bitrate=7984.2kbits/s speed=0.65x    
frame= 1367 fps= 20 q=23.0 size=   42752kB time=00:00:43.61 bitrate=8030.8kbits/s speed=0.653x    
frame= 1379 fps= 20 q=23.0 size=   43264kB time=00:00:44.01 bitrate=8053.0kbits/s speed=0.654x    
frame= 1383 fps= 20 q=23.0 size=   43520kB time=00:00:44.14 bitrate=8076.2kbits/s speed=0.651x    
frame= 1389 fps= 20 q=22.0 size=   43776kB time=00:00:44.34 bitrate=8087.0kbits/s speed=0.649x    
frame= 1394 fps= 20 q=24.0 size=   44032kB time=00:00:44.51 bitrate=8103.8kbits/s speed=0.647x    
frame= 1400 fps= 20 q=26.0 size=   44288kB time=00:00:44.71 bitrate=8114.4kbits/s speed=0.645x    
frame= 1406 fps= 20 q=25.0 size=   44544kB time=00:00:44.91 bitrate=8124.9kbits/s speed=0.643x    
frame= 1415 fps= 20 q=24.0 size=   45056kB time=00:00:45.21 bitrate=8163.7kbits/s speed=0.643x    
frame= 1431 fps= 20 q=24.0 size=   45824kB time=00:00:45.74 bitrate=8206.0kbits/s speed=0.646x    
frame= 1446 fps= 20 q=25.0 size=   46592kB time=00:00:46.24 bitrate=8253.2kbits/s speed=0.648x    
frame= 1461 fps= 20 q=24.0 size=   46848kB time=00:00:46.74 bitrate=8209.7kbits/s speed=0.651x    
frame= 1475 fps= 20 q=26.0 size=   47104kB time=00:00:47.21 bitrate=8172.9kbits/s speed=0.653x    
frame= 1491 fps= 20 q=24.0 size=   47360kB time=00:00:47.74 bitrate=8125.5kbits/s speed=0.655x    
frame= 1507 fps= 21 q=25.0 size=   47616kB time=00:00:48.28 bitrate=8079.1kbits/s speed=0.658x    
frame= 1522 fps= 21 q=24.0 size=   47872kB time=00:00:48.78 bitrate=8039.2kbits/s speed=0.66x    
frame= 1538 fps= 21 q=25.0 size=   48384kB time=00:00:49.31 bitrate=8037.2kbits/s speed=0.663x    
frame= 1553 fps= 21 q=23.0 size=   48640kB time=00:00:49.81 bitrate=7998.5kbits/s speed=0.665x    
frame= 1568 fps= 21 q=25.0 size=   48896kB time=00:00:50.31 bitrate=7960.6kbits/s speed=0.667x    
frame= 1581 fps= 21 q=23.0 size=   49152kB time=00:00:50.75 bitrate=7933.9kbits/s speed=0.669x    
frame= 1596 fps= 21 q=25.0 size=   49664kB time=00:00:51.25 bitrate=7938.3kbits/s speed=0.671x    
frame= 1613 fps= 21 q=19.0 size=   49920kB time=00:00:51.81 bitrate=7891.9kbits/s speed=0.674x    
frame= 1629 fps= 21 q=16.0 size=   50176kB time=00:00:52.35 bitrate=7851.4kbits/s speed=0.676x    
frame= 1644 fps= 21 q=15.0 size=   50688kB time=00:00:52.85 bitrate=7856.5kbits/s speed=0.678x    
frame= 1660 fps= 21 q=19.0 size=   50944kB time=00:00:53.38 bitrate=7817.2kbits/s speed=0.68x    
frame= 1673 fps= 21 q=16.0 size=   50944kB time=00:00:53.82 bitrate=7754.2kbits/s speed=0.682x    
frame= 1686 fps= 21 q=17.0 size=   51200kB time=00:00:54.25 bitrate=7730.8kbits/s speed=0.683x    
frame= 1699 fps= 21 q=23.0 size=   51456kB time=00:00:54.68 bitrate=7707.9kbits/s speed=0.684x    
frame= 1712 fps= 21 q=23.0 size=   51456kB time=00:00:55.12 bitrate=7647.2kbits/s speed=0.685x    
frame= 1723 fps= 21 q=20.0 size=   51456kB time=00:00:55.48 bitrate=7596.6kbits/s speed=0.685x    
frame= 1736 fps= 21 q=20.0 size=   51712kB time=00:00:55.92 bitrate=7575.2kbits/s speed=0.686x    
frame= 1751 fps= 21 q=22.0 size=   52224kB time=00:00:56.42 bitrate=7582.3kbits/s speed=0.688x    
frame= 1765 fps= 21 q=21.0 size=   52480kB time=00:00:56.89 bitrate=7556.9kbits/s speed=0.689x    
frame= 1779 fps= 21 q=24.0 size=   53248kB time=00:00:57.35 bitrate=7605.1kbits/s speed=0.691x    
frame= 1794 fps= 21 q=24.0 size=   53760kB time=00:00:57.85 bitrate=7611.8kbits/s speed=0.693x    
frame= 1810 fps= 22 q=24.0 size=   54272kB time=00:00:58.39 bitrate=7614.0kbits/s speed=0.695x    
frame= 1827 fps= 22 q=20.0 size=   55040kB time=00:00:58.95 bitrate=7647.5kbits/s speed=0.697x    
frame= 1843 fps= 22 q=22.0 size=   55552kB time=00:00:59.49 bitrate=7649.4kbits/s speed=0.699x    
frame= 1859 fps= 22 q=19.0 size=   56064kB time=00:01:00.02 bitrate=7651.2kbits/s speed=0.701x    
frame= 1874 fps= 22 q=20.0 size=   56320kB time=00:01:00.52 bitrate=7622.6kbits/s speed=0.703x    
frame= 1887 fps= 22 q=23.0 size=   57088kB time=00:01:00.96 bitrate=7671.5kbits/s speed=0.704x    
frame= 1900 fps= 22 q=22.0 size=   57344kB time=00:01:01.39 bitrate=7651.5kbits/s speed=0.705x    
frame= 1914 fps= 22 q=22.0 size=   57856kB time=00:01:01.86 bitrate=7661.5kbits/s speed=0.706x    
frame= 1925 fps= 22 q=22.0 size=   58368kB time=00:01:02.22 bitrate=7683.7kbits/s speed=0.706x    
frame= 1938 fps= 22 q=24.0 size=   58624kB time=00:01:02.66 bitrate=7664.0kbits/s speed=0.707x    
frame= 1954 fps= 22 q=23.0 size=   59392kB time=00:01:03.19 bitrate=7698.8kbits/s speed=0.709x    
frame= 1969 fps= 22 q=21.0 size=   59648kB time=00:01:03.69 bitrate=7671.3kbits/s speed=0.71x    
frame= 1979 fps= 22 q=-1.0 Lsize=   62073kB time=00:01:05.93 bitrate=7712.4kbits/s speed=0.732x    
video:62051kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.035899%
[libx264 @ 000001f00526ec00] frame I:10    Avg QP:15.73  size:237324
[libx264 @ 000001f00526ec00] frame P:795   Avg QP:21.37  size: 52874
[libx264 @ 000001f00526ec00] frame B:1174  Avg QP:21.50  size: 16295
[libx264 @ 000001f00526ec00] consecutive B-frames: 17.5%  7.9%  6.7% 67.9%
[libx264 @ 000001f00526ec00] mb I  I16..4: 21.9% 28.8% 49.4%
[libx264 @ 000001f00526ec00] mb P  I16..4:  3.5%  3.9%  1.7%  P16..4: 55.8%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:35.2%
[libx264 @ 000001f00526ec00] mb B  I16..4:  0.2%  0.2%  0.1%  B16..8: 21.8%  0.0%  0.0%  direct:11.7%  skip:65.9%  L0:39.7% L1:45.1% BI:15.2%
[libx264 @ 000001f00526ec00] final ratefactor: 22.21
[libx264 @ 000001f00526ec00] 8x8 transform intra:40.9% inter:34.1%
[libx264 @ 000001f00526ec00] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 51.3% 33.7% 14.7% inter: 17.0% 8.1% 0.6%
[libx264 @ 000001f00526ec00] i16 v,h,dc,p: 59% 22% 14%  5%
[libx264 @ 000001f00526ec00] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 17% 27% 22%  5%  5%  4%  8%  4%  8%
[libx264 @ 000001f00526ec00] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 24% 25% 14%  6%  6%  5%  8%  4%  9%
[libx264 @ 000001f00526ec00] i8c dc,h,v,p: 55% 23% 14%  7%
[libx264 @ 000001f00526ec00] Weighted P-Frames: Y:6.9% UV:5.2%
[libx264 @ 000001f00526ec00] kb/s:7697.90
```

Is there anyway to fix this?

#### Edit:

My MoviePy version is 1.0.1, and Python version is 3.8.8.

Comment: instead of logger=None, enable logger by passing other suitable argument and then in verbose output check the actual problem or error what causing this behaviour .

Comment: @ZainUlAbidin You mean change `logger=None` to?

Comment: @U12-Forward have you used any codec for the output?

Comment: @AbhinavMathur I tried a lot, but none of them worked... Do you have any ideas?

Comment: @U12-Forward what is the duration of `for_delivery` and `music_file`?

Comment: @AbhinavMathur 66 and for music file it is 240.82

Comment: Yes @U12-Forward enable logger by attaching any standard python logger it will show you the detail logs like warnings of your codecs problems or audio processing logs

Comment: @ZainUlAbidin Hmm.. Which are standard python loggers?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html check this

Comment: @ZainUlAbidin Could your provide an answer??

Comment: @U12-Forward you'll need to add the logger and attach the log to this question for debugging to be possible

Comment: @AbhinavMathur I used `write_logfile=True` and it gives what I just edited into my question

Comment: @ZainUlAbidin ^

Comment: @U12-Forward according to the logs, you are using the duration of your video to cut the audio but your video has no duration available . can you test it by putting some hard coded value just for testing instead of current dynamic approach

Comment: music_file.subclip(0, for_delivery.duration) in this line of code

Comment: @ZainUlAbidin I did `subclip(0, 66)` on both the audio and the video and still gives the same logfile...

Comment: That means, your encoders are not encoding the video right way because beside hard coded values your length duration is not being considered its still showing as NA (Not Available) check your video codecs try to change your codec

Comment: @ZainUlAbidin The current video's codec is H264 and it's audio (which I am not using is AAC). And the codec of the music file I am using is also AAC... Do you know anyway to make this work?

Comment: @ZainUlAbidin FYI, my moviepy version is 1.0.1

Comment: @ZainUlAbidin I fixed it.. it is actually a bug... Check my answer below

Comment: @AbhinavMathur ^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized this is a bug with `moviepy`... In my version (`1.0.1`), in the backend of `moviepy` there is an `ffmpeg` parameter that is `-an`... As mentioned in the [documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Audio-Options), `-an` disables all audio streams of the video. It says:

> As an input option, blocks all audio streams of a file from being
> filtered or being automatically selected or mapped for any output. See
> `-discard` option to disable streams individually.
>
> As an output option, disables audio recording i.e. automatic selection
> or mapping of any audio stream. For full manual control see the `-map`
> option.

So the fix was to go into the `site-packages` and update the `moviepy` backend code. I saw this on [GitHub](https://github.com/Zulko/moviepy/issues/1032).

So open `<path to your site-packages>\site-packages\moviepy\video\io\ffmpeg_writer.py`, and go to line 86 and change the line from:

```
            '-i', '-', '-an',
```

To:

```
            '-i', '-'#, '-an',
```

So, in other words, if your `moviepy` version is currently `1.0.1`, either update your version to a higher version, or comment out the `'-an'` parameter in the ffmpeg command.

It's a real pity that I have to spent an entire day trying to fix this problem that I am not causing... I tried all suggested solutions of changing codecs, keeping `audio_tempfile`s, adding `ffmpeg_params` and much more.

I am answering my own question so that if others stumble onto this same trouble, they don't need to beat their brains out for a day, they can just take a look at this question.

So, hope it helped...

Comment: Well done (Y), are these params are highlighted in the log file you posted? or you find this bug from some where else?

Comment: @ZainUlAbidin I found it on GitHub