# Add audio to video using moviepy

Tags: python, moviepy

Title basically explains it. Trying to add audio to a video. I have a sequence of mp3 files that I want to play sequentially during the video. There're no errors or anything with the code but when I run the code theres still no audio in the video. Just a recreation of the old video with no audio (the original video doesnt have audio either).

```
video = VideoFileClip("finished_video.mp4")
title_clip = AudioFileClip("title.mp3")

audio_list = [title_clip]

for x in range(1, counter):
    audio = AudioFileClip("p{}.mp3".format(x))
    audio_list.append(audio)

video.set_audio(audio_list)
video.write_videofile("new_filename.mp4")
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Moviepy: add audio to a video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55032551/moviepy-add-audio-to-a-video)

Comment: Yes I tried this. Everything works with no errors. However, when I click the video I am still getting no audio. Am I possibly missing something?

Comment: Use `CompositeAudioClip` as in the other post.

Comment: Yes I did try running that code as well. Not sure what is wrong

Answer (score 0):

it works for me

```
from moviepy.editor import *
videoclip = VideoFileClip("sample.mp4")
audioclip = AudioFileClip("sample_audio.mp3")

new_audioclip = CompositeAudioClip([audioclip])
videoclip.audio = new_audioclip
videoclip.write_videofile("output.mp4")
```

use CompositeAudioClip to merge both files.

Comment: Yes I tried running that code as well exactly. Not sure why it is not working for me. Any possible ideas?

Comment: can you try it with different audio and video file! check if there is any issue with your input file

Comment: clip = VideoFileClip("finished_video.mp4")
  
# getting only first 5 seconds
clip = clip.subclip(0, 30)
  
# loading audio file
audioclip = AudioFileClip("p2.mp3").subclip(0, 23)
  
# adding audio to the video clip
videoclip = clip.set_audio(audioclip)
  
# showing video clip
videoclip.write_videofile("finished_video2.mp4")
videoclip.ipython_display()

When I run it with this code and display it, the audio comes. However, when I open the finished_video2.mp4 on my computer, it has no audio. Any ideas?

Comment: if possible can you send your media files in drive! It works fine with my end! the only difference is I have used CompositeAudioClip([audioclip])

Comment: Sure! How can I send them?

Comment: put them in google drive with access!

Comment: Can I email them to you instead?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246308/discussion-between-hari-prasad-and-jatin-shekara).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. It seems like `set_audio()` doesn't actually set it, but returns the new video combined with the audio.

This is the way I did it :

```py
final_video = video.set_audio(audio_list)
final_video.write_videofile("new_filename.mp4")
```

Hope that helps !

Answer (score 0):

This is what works for me using `moviepy`:

```py
videoclip = VideoFileClip(f'{audioless_video_path}')
audioclip = AudioFileClip(f'{new_audio_clip_path}')
new_audioclip = CompositeAudioClip([audioclip])
videoclip.audio = new_audioclip
videoclip.write_videofile(f'{new_video_file_with_audio_path}')
```